# Nil relationship value for section name key path in nsfetchedresultscontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-data

For a core data model where EntityA has a many-to-one relationship with EntityB, I want to create a list of EntityA objects, sorted by the name of the EntityB they are related to. Normally to do this I would set up the fetch request like this:

```
if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
```

Then I would set up my request's values: (in this case it's a list of plants sorted by species name. some plants have no species set.)

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Plant" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorOne = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"species.name" ascending:YES];
NSString *sectionKeyPath = @"species.name";
```

Then I finish it up with the usual stuff:

```
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// Set the batch size to a suitable number.
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptorOne];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
sectionNameKeyPath:sectionKeyPath
cacheName:@"plantsCache"];

aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"plantsCache"];
NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

return _fetchedResultsController;
```

But the result I get isn't working for me because the relationship is optional. So some of EntityA have a relationship to EntityB's and some don't. The results controller doesn't seem to know what to do when the value of EntityA's relationship is nil.

Any suggestions what I can do to continue making sections using the relationship's value but allowing some objects to have nil for it?

Comment: EntityA is Plant and EntityB is Species? Then the one-to-many relationship is from EntityB to EntityA, and not the other way around as in your first sentence? - What does actually happen with the plants that are not related to a species? Are they not fetched, not displayed, ... ?

Comment: You're right I got it backwards. I meant that EntityA (the plant) has a many-to-one relationship with EntityB (the species). Plants that are not related to any species show up in a blank (unnamed) section and core data complains to the console. This behaviour is actually what I want. But if I return to the list view from a detail view, having added a plant with no species, the list will not show the additional plant item until the fetchedresultscontroller is called again. Optimally I'd like not to have to refill the results control on viewWillAppear.

Comment: The unnamed section problem (and the complaint) can perhaps be solved adding a method (or transient property) `sectionName` to the Plant entity and using that as `sectionNameKeyPath`. That method should return either `self.species.name` or an empty string. - I cannot test this at the moment, so I don't know if that really helps.

Answer (score 3):

Set up a transient property in `Plant` like this:

```
-(NSString*)speciesName {
    return self.species ? self.species.name : @"";
}
```

You can now use `speciesName` as the `sectionNameKeyPath`.

Comment: Would that also need to be in the core data model or just the entity's class file?

Comment: Needs to be in the model. Mark it as "Transient" in the model editor.

Comment: (That is exactly what I suggested in my above comment.) - And I do *not* think that you have to define it as a transient property in the Core Data model. A simple method in the entity's class should be sufficient.

Comment: I found some more about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359437/core-data-using-transient-properties-in-group-by). The transient property works great as the section key, but it doesn't work for sort descriptors. That seems to be fine as long as the transient property is sorting the same as the sort property (if that makes sense).

Comment: The FRC just calls `[object valueForKeyPath:keyPath]` for each fetched object, where `keyPath` is the sectionNameKeyPath, and KVC will translate that to `[object keyPath]` if such a method is present.

Comment: OK, thanks for pointing out the detail about the sorting. I think that would be guaranteed to work as expected if it is in the model, while relying on something unrelated would not.

Comment: @jedipixel: That makes sense. That is why I only suggested to use the method/property as sectionNameKeyPath. You still have to use `species.name` as sort descriptor key. And the relative ordering has to be the same. So if the sort descriptor sorts all `nil` entries first then your sectionNameKeyPath method must also sort these entries first. This would be the case if `nil` is translated to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this with Swift 3.0.  Had two entities EntityA and EntityB, where EntityA usually belongs to (has a pointer to) some EntityB, but may be unowned as well.

The Swift fix was to add an extension to EntityA that returns an empty String if a nil condition is detected.

```
extension Note {
    var bookTitleOrNil : String {
        if let bookTitle = self.book?.title {
            return bookTitle
        }
        return ""
    }
}
```

Then replace following in building the fetchRequestController (FRC):

```
let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.coreDataManager.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "book.title", cacheName: nil)
```

With using the new extension for the sectionNameKeyPath:

```
let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.coreDataManager.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "bookTitleOrNil", cacheName: nil)
```

Then, when generating headers for the different sections, I used the following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let useIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: section) // Get first item in section (all notes in a section point to same book)
    let note = frc.object(at: useIndexPath)
    if let bookTitle = note.book?.title {
        return bookTitle
    } else {
        return "Unlinked"
    }
}
```

So the notes come out sorted first by the book they belong to as shown by the section header (though notes that don't belong to any book come out sorted first under the "Unlinked" header).

Also, in setting up the sorting in the fetchRequest of the FRC, one needs to set up the primary sort descriptor to use book.title and then any additional sorting, such as the note's title.

```
let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "book.title", ascending: true)
let sortDescriptor2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2]
```

Of course, one could also design the app so that a note always belongs to a book by extra checks when a note is created and avoid the nil case that way.